# Power BI Data Label issue

Tags: powerbi

I have createe a Clustered Column Chart and I'm using a measure as a value. the problem is that all columns show the right data with the right data label except on column which only shows the text `6.43E-8`.

How can I change this to show the right units (Millions) and remove the `E` from the Data label?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Format -- > Data Label --> Display Units`
I have attached picture for reference.

**Screenshot:**

[image: imgur]

Comment: thanks for the answer but i fix the issue.the problem was not the display unit as you mention but the number it s self.it was to small and i user round function to overcome this problem.

Comment: If you found a solution, please write it up as an answer so that others on the forum will benefit. And even if those who tried to find a perfect solution for you were not 100% successful, please consider giving an upvote if it was helpful in any way. StackOverflow (arguably) needs more Power BI activity, and voting sure does not hurt.